# kalendae not working properly with other stylesheets and script src

Tags: css

I'm using kalendae calendar in my site.When there are no other stylsheets other than kalendae's stylesheet and script src then it works properly.But when i add all of them then it behave abnormally.I also tried removing all the links one by one to see what is causing the problem but could not figure it out.It only works normally when i remove all the stylesheets and script src.Here are the two images that will make my question clear.
 When i remove all stylesheets and script src

[image]

After adding them

[image]

And here are the stylesheets and script src.I'm really sorry for using so many bootstrap link but some were not doing the tasks i wanted so i added so many of them.

```
<script src="build/kalendae.standalone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="js/wheelnav.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/wheelnav.js"></script>
<script src="js/raphael.icons.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/raphael.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/Livie_ccs1.css">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Please help.

Here is the code for kalendae

```
<html>
<head> 
    <title>JavaScript calendar</title>

    <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="build/kalendae.standalone.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="auto-kal" ></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle link. https://fiddle.jshell.net/qyf96yrk/.
The Kalandae is not appearing on the fiddle though i have added the link.Also the src code is very long.That is the reason why i was not adding my code.Sorry for the onconvenience

Comment: How are we supposed to help exactly? I don't see any HTML here. You expect us to go through every stylesheet and script and just guess as to why the elements don't look right on whatever page you're talking about?

Comment: It is happening due to the stylesheets and script src.That's why i'm not adding the code.Anyways i will add the Kalendae's code.Sorry for the incovenience

Comment: Clearly you have things interfering with one another, but until we can inspect the element ourselves we have no idea what's affecting what, which is why I ask for some HTML or something like a fiddle which demonstrates the example in a way we can work with.

Comment: I'm adding the fiddle link